# How to fetch orders from past x hours via Shopware Admin API?

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

The POST request to the **https://shop-URL/api/search/order** endpoint requires a filter in order to return a specific selection.

I can't any examples or proper documentation about what the payload would have to look like in order to be able to fetch orders in between certain dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a filter. The filter has to look like this:

```
{
  "type": "range",
  "field": "createdAt",
  "parameters": {
    "lte": "2021-01-17T12: 00: 00.333+00: 00"
  }
}
```

Of course this is only an example and needs adjustment or multiple range filters to deliver the right result.

Comment: I had already found the answer, but like a typical StackOverflow post I forgot to post it. My findings were the same as yours, my full payload ended up being:

{
    "filter": [
        { 
            "type": "range", 
            "field": "createdAt", 
            "parameters": {
                "gte": "2022-05-30T09:54:53.250+00:00",      
                "lte": "2022-05-31T01:54:53.250+00:00"  
            }
        }    
    ]
}

I'll mark your reply as the answer anyway ;-)